# Custom API Integration Won't Work For All Salesforce Editions?

Tags: rest-api, api, integration, editions

A custom integration has been set up, and currently getting a `Invalid Session ID` error when trying to call API endpoints with valid authorization token and instance url which are generated during oAuth process. Endpoints are working fine when using a developer edition. On the docs it says API is disabled for 3 editions. So the endpoint calls should work for the other editions right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , as per the docs API access is not provided for below editions :

- Group Edition
- Essentials Edition
- Professional Edition (can be purchased as an add-on)

Reference : https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385436&type=1

But you will not get `Invalid Session ID` in that case.
If API access is disabled, the error message is : `API not enabled for this Organization or Partner`

Reference : https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385535&type=1

Comment: Ah okay, so for instance when the add-on is purchased for the Professional edition, calls to the API endpoints that are currently in place(for editions allowing API access) can go through right? No other setting modification would be required from their end - besides enabling API access?

Comment: Yes. Additionally ,the Salesforce user which would be configured for integration will require "API Enabled" permission via profile or permission set. You can refer the 2nd link in my answer.

Comment: Okay, thank you!

Comment: @JXS : Welcome. Not specific to this answer but once your question is answered it's a best practise to accept that as the answer since it helps for anyone visiting in the future to know it. Also , it adds up to the reputation and encourages people to answer more questions.